# How to use OneToMany and ManyToOne with two entities that result from named queries in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have this two clases:

```
package cu.jpa.entities.views;

import cu.jpa.entities.BaseEntity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(
        name="SubstanceDescriptionEntity.findAll",
        query="select " +
                "    new cu.jpa.entities.views.SubstanceDescriptionEntity(S.id, S.substanceId) " +
                "from " +
                "    SubstanceEntity S "
)
public class SubstanceDescriptionEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private int id;
    private String substanceId;
    private List<PatternDescriptionEntity> patterns;

    public SubstanceDescriptionEntity(int id, String substanceId){
        this.id = id;
        this.substanceId = substanceId;
    }
    public SubstanceDescriptionEntity(){

    }


    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubstanceId() {
        return substanceId;
    }

    public void setSubstanceId(String substanceId) {
        this.substanceId = substanceId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "substance")
    public List<PatternDescriptionEntity> getPatterns() {
        return patterns;
    }

    public void setPatterns(List<PatternDescriptionEntity> patterns) {
        this.patterns = patterns;
    }
}
```

This is class 2:

```
package cu.jpa.entities.views;

import cu.jpa.entities.BaseEntity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(
        name="PatternDescriptionEntity.findAll",
        query="select " +
                "    new cu.jpa.entities.views.PatternDescriptionEntity(P.id, " +
                "    E.encounterId, " +
                "    P.patternId, " +
                "    E.substanceId) " +
                "from " +
                "    PatternEntity P " +
                "    inner join " +
                "    P.encounterByEncounterId E " +
                "    where P.encounterId = E.id "
)
public class PatternDescriptionEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private int id;
    private String patternId;
    private String encounterId;
    private int substanceId;

    private SubstanceDescriptionEntity substance;

    public PatternDescriptionEntity(int id, String encounterId, String patternId,  int substanceId){
        this.id = id;
        this.patternId = patternId;
        this.encounterId = encounterId;
        this.substanceId = substanceId;
    }
    public PatternDescriptionEntity(){

    }


    @Id
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPatternId() {
        return patternId;
    }

    public void setPatternId(String patternId) {
        this.patternId = patternId;
    }

    public String getEncounterId() {
        return encounterId;
    }

    public void setEncounterId(String encounterId) {
        this.encounterId = encounterId;
    }

    public int getSubstanceId() {
        return substanceId;
    }

    public void setSubstanceId(int substanceId) {
        this.substanceId = substanceId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "substanceId", insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "substanceId")
    public SubstanceDescriptionEntity getSubstance() {
        return substance;
    }

    public void setSubstance(SubstanceDescriptionEntity substance) {
        this.substance = substance;
    }
}
```

Both classes are the result of a named query execution. I can get all the elements correctly using this:

```
@Override
public List<PatternDescriptionEntity> findAll(){
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("PatternDescriptionEntity.findAll",PatternDescriptionEntity.class);
    List<PatternDescriptionEntity> items =  query.getResultList();
    return items;
}
```

The problem is that I would like to get the reference to the **SubstanceDescriptionEntity** that corresponds to the **PatternDescriptionEntity**, according to the details I think I should have placed in @ManyToOne annotation. Both entities are the result of a named query, not of a table mapping. That is why I am having troubles. Because when I execute this test:

```
@Autowired
PatternDescriptionService service;

@Test
public void test_count_with_filters() throws Exception {
    List<PatternDescriptionEntity> patterns = service.findAll();
}
```

I can see the **patterns** list with values, but each individual instance of the list has the property **substance** in null, which means the mapping have some sort of trouble, which I can quite figure it out.
So the question is:
I have these two JPA Entities (not mapped to database tables, but to to named queries result). How can I define the relations of ManyToOne and OneToMany?

Comment: Entities are always mapped to a tables, not to queries! So I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If you see _SubstanceDescriptionEntity_ and _PatternDescriptionEntity_, I am not defining any table. These entities are not mapped to any tables. This works, I can get the results when I execute the _findAll_ method.

Comment: They are annotated by Entity on top! The table will be SubstanceDescriptionEntity or Substance_Description_Entity be default

Comment: And if you want arbitratry class returned from named query, then of course they cannot have any relations populated as they will be treated in the same way as for example String or Integer and not managed by JPA

Comment: The class returned from the named query is an Entity, not just some arbitrary class. Both classes are related through the _substanceId_ property, isn't there a way to get that relation mapped?

Comment: "The NEW operator can be used with the fully qualified class name to return data objects from a JPQL query. These will not be managed objects!!!" Why are you using constructor for the Entity in the first place. Is your query like that by mistake or on purpose?

Comment: It's like this on purpose. This was the only way I could find to map the columns returned from the named query to my Entity. Is there another way? I need to use the _typed_ version of createNamedQuery, that is why I use the **new** operator inside the query.